# No adapter attached skipping layout for recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Hi in the below code I am getting the below error for displaying a list using recyclerview .
When I am trying to display the list I am getting the below error.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to helper.GetBuildingList
        at com.deepshikha.lightingsystem.SwipeRecyclerViewAdapter.onBindViewHolder(SwipeRecyclerViewAdapter.java:41)
        at com.deepshikha.lightingsystem.SwipeRecyclerViewAdapter.onBindViewHolder(SwipeRecyclerViewAdapter.java:22)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6781)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6823)
```

Response :

```
[{"ID":"1","Name":"Building1"},{"ID":"2","Name":"appexx"}]
```

In the below adapter displays the what are the item presents in the getbuildinglist pojo class.As well as Once user swiped from right to left .We are displaying two options for the list items to edit and delete the items.

SwipeAdapter:

```
public class SwipeRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerSwipeAdapter<SwipeRecyclerViewAdapter.SimpleViewHolder> {


    private Context mContext;
    private List<GetBuildingList> buildingLists;

    public SwipeRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List<GetBuildingList> strings) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.buildingLists = strings;
    }

    @Override
    public SimpleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_item, parent, false);
        return new SimpleViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final SimpleViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
        final GetBuildingList item = buildingLists.get(position);
        System.out.println ("item"+item);

        viewHolder.tvName.setText((item.getName ()) + "  -  Row Position " + position);
        System.out.println (item.getName ());


        viewHolder.swipeLayout.setShowMode(SwipeLayout.ShowMode.PullOut);

        // Drag From Left
//        viewHolder.swipeLayout.addDrag(SwipeLayout.DragEdge.Left, viewHolder.swipeLayout.findViewById(R.id.bottom_wrapper1));

        // Drag From Right
        viewHolder.swipeLayout.addDrag(SwipeLayout.DragEdge.Right, viewHolder.swipeLayout.findViewById(R.id.bottom_wrapper));


        // Handling different events when swiping
        viewHolder.swipeLayout.addSwipeListener(new SwipeLayout.SwipeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClose(SwipeLayout layout) {
                //when the SurfaceView totally cover the BottomView.
            }

            @Override
            public void onUpdate(SwipeLayout layout, int leftOffset, int topOffset) {
                //you are swiping.
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartOpen(SwipeLayout layout) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onOpen(SwipeLayout layout) {
                //when the BottomView totally show.
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartClose(SwipeLayout layout) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onHandRelease(SwipeLayout layout, float xvel, float yvel) {
                //when user's hand released.
            }
        });

        /*viewHolder.swipeLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                if ((((SwipeLayout) v).getOpenStatus() == SwipeLayout.Status.Close)) {
                    //Start your activity

                    Toast.makeText(mContext, " onClick : " + item.getName() + " \n" + item.getEmailId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        });*/

        viewHolder.swipeLayout.getSurfaceView().setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, " onClick : " + item.getName () + " \n" + item.getID (), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });


//        viewHolder.btnLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
//            @Override
//            public void onClick(View v) {
//
//                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Clicked on Map " + viewHolder.tvName.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//            }
//        });
//
//
//        viewHolder.tvShare.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
//            @Override
//            public void onClick(View view) {
//
//                Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Clicked on Share " + viewHolder.tvName.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//            }
//        });

        viewHolder.tvEdit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Clicked on Edit  " + viewHolder.tvName.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });


        viewHolder.tvDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mItemManger.removeShownLayouts(viewHolder.swipeLayout);
                buildingLists.remove(position);
                notifyItemRemoved(position);
                notifyItemRangeChanged(position, buildingLists.size());
                mItemManger.closeAllItems();
                Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Deleted " + viewHolder.tvName.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });


        // mItemManger is member in RecyclerSwipeAdapter Class
        mItemManger.bindView(viewHolder.itemView, position);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return buildingLists.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getSwipeLayoutResourceId(int position) {
        return R.id.swipe;
    }


    //  ViewHolder Class

    public static class SimpleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        SwipeLayout swipeLayout;
        TextView tvName;
        TextView tvDelete;
        TextView tvEdit;


        public SimpleViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            swipeLayout = (SwipeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.swipe);
            tvName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
         //   tvEmailId = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvEmailId);
            tvDelete = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvDelete);
            tvEdit = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvEdit);
          //  tvShare = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvShare);
         //   btnLocation = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnLocation);


        }
    }
}
```

In the below code describes the without refreshing the activity I am getting the response from the server.
That response I am adding to arraylist then setting the adapter to the recyclerview to display the list of items with swipe options.

Add.java:

```
private void doTheAutoRefresh() {
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Write code for your refresh logic

                progressDialog = new ProgressDialog (getActivity ());
                progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
                progressDialog.setMessage("Communicating...");
                progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
                progressDialog.show();
                OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                        .connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                        .writeTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                        .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                        .build();

                Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                        .baseUrl(API.URL_BASE)
                        .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
                        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                        .client (client)
                        .build();
                API service = retrofit.create (API.class);
                Call<List<GetBuildingList>> userCall = service.getbuildinglist ();
                userCall.enqueue(new Callback<List<GetBuildingList>> () {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call <List<GetBuildingList>> call, Response <List<GetBuildingList>> response) {


                        if(response.isSuccessful()) {
                            progressDialog.dismiss ( );
                            Log.d ("Response body", new Gson ( ).toJson (response.body ( )));
                            String Status = new Gson ( ).toJson (response.body ( ));
                            JSONArray jsonArray = null;

                            try {
                                JSONObject jsonObject=null;
                                jsonArray = new JSONArray (Status);
                                arrayList = new ArrayList <> ( );

                                for (int i=0;i<jsonArray.length ();i++) {
                                    name=jsonArray.getJSONObject (i).getString ("Name");


                                    arrayList.add (name);

                                }

                                // Creating Adapter object
                                SwipeRecyclerViewAdapter mAdapter = new SwipeRecyclerViewAdapter((Context) getActivity (), arrayList);
                                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged ();
                                mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);



                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace ( );

                            }

                        }

                        else  {
                            progressDialog.dismiss ();
                            Log.d("Response errorBody", String.valueOf(response.errorBody()));
                        }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<List<GetBuildingList>> call, Throwable t) {
                        // lv.setAdapter (adapter);
                        System.out.println("onFailure");
                        System.out.println(t.fillInStackTrace());
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity (), "Some error occurred -> ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();;
                        // progressDialog.dismiss();



                    }

                });
            }


        }, 5000);
        return ;
    }
```

GetBuildingList.java:

```
public class GetBuildingList{

    @SerializedName("ID")
    private String ID;

    @SerializedName("Name")
    private String Name;

    public String getID() {
        return ID;
    }

    public void setID(String ID) {
        this.ID = ID;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        Name = name;
    }


}
```

Comment: `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to helper.GetBuildingList` tells you that you can transform a bike into a strawberry.

Answer (score 1):

In your `onResponse()` method you have these lines:

```
name=jsonArray.getJSONObject (i).getString ("Name");
...
arrayList.add (name);
```

Then you pass this list to your adapter. This list is assigned to the `GetBuildingList` field of your adapter. Then in your adapter you do:

```
final GetBuildingList item = buildingLists.get(position);
```

So you're trying to cast `String` type to `GetBuildingList` type, hence the exception.

Not really familiar with the library but you should try something like this:

```
for (int i=0;i<jsonArray.length ();i++) {
    String name = jsonArray.getJSONObject (i).getString ("Name");
    String id = jsonArray.getJSONObject (i).getString ("Id");
    GetBuildingList gbl = new GetBuildingList();
    gbl.setId(id);
    gbl.setName(name);
    arrayList.add(gbl);
}
```

I haven't used this library yet so if I'm wrong, someone please correct the above sample.

Comment: You are only passing the name of the objects to the adapter, not the full objects. Edited my answer.

Comment: final GetBuildingList item = buildingLists.get(position); for this line I am getting error

Comment: Yes, because your `buildingLists` contains strings and your `item` is of the type `GetBuildingList`.

Comment: But response contains list of strings

Comment: How to change building list to arraylist